# html scraping, getting different values with the same name

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

since there is no api for the website which i would like to get csgo stats from, i am attempting to scrape from the website, i know how to load the website and such, like print the main page, but i cannot figure out how to load specific values because most of them have the same name as you will see below. i am attempting to get the value of win% and the value of kd but both of the classes are called "stats-stat", any way i can do this?

my code is:

```
var UR_L = "http://csgo.tracker.network/profile/blind_snip"; 

request(UR_L, function(err, resp, body){
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  console.log(body)
})
```

[image]

UPDATE: my working code:

```
 var UR_L = "http://csgo.tracker.network/profile/blind_snip"; 

 request(UR_L, function(err, resp, body){

     $ = cheerio.load(body);
     var ele = $('.stats-stat').eq(13).text();
       ele2 = $.parseHTML(ele)[0].data;
       console.log(ele2);


       //0 = KD
       //1 = win%
       //2 = games
       //3 = wins
       //4 = headshots
       //5 = money earned
       //6 = score
       //7 = kills
       //8 = Deaths
       //9 = MVP
       //10 = time played
       //11 = Rounds played
       //12 = rounds won
       //13 = bombs set
       //14 = bombs defused
       //15 = hostages rescued
  })
```

Thanks people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got as far as getting the string value, you could use a regex to get the part you need. If you just console out ele, you'll see it starts with /n/n. Also notice that i am using .eq and selecting the index i want. you could loop over the query selector instead.

```
request(UR_L, function(err, resp, body){

  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  var ele = $('.stats-stat').eq(1).text();
    console.log($.parseHTML(ele)[0].data);

})
```

Comment: ok thanks, i will look at it now and try to get the value, thanks for helping